# Best way to efficiently find high density regions

Tags: algorithm, search, math, optimization

Over the course of my coding, I have come across a problem as follows:
Find the a region of fixed size in a 2D space that has the highest density of particles. The particles can be considered generally distributed randomly over the entire space, but in theory there should be some areas that have a higher density.

For example, 100 particles are placed randomly in a 2D grid that is 500x500, and I need to find the 50x50 region with the most particles (highest density).

Is there some other way to calculate the best region besides brute force testing every possible region (in this case about over 200000 regions)? That would scale up at O(n^2) for an n-length axis.

Comment: @MillieSmith: That's a nice idea, but it's not very helpful unless you have an idea of how many queries are necessary.

Comment: It's exactly the same as this problem: http://poj.org/problem?id=1916 for which the best solution is `O(N^2 + K*D^2)` where `K` is the number of particles (in your case it's 100) and `D` is the size of the region (in your case it's 50), as shown in this C++ code: http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/uva-10360-rat-attack/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Algorithm 1

Create a 500x500 2D array, where each cell contains the count of the number of particles in that cell.  Then convolve that array with a 50x50 kernel, the resulting array will have the count of particles in a 50x50 region in each cell.  Then find the cell with the largest value.

If you are using a 50x50 box as a region, the kernel can be decomposed into two separate convolutions, one for each axis.  The resulting algorithm is O(n^2) space and time, where n is the width and height of the 2D space you are searching.

As a reminder, a one-dimensional convolution with a boxcar function can be completed in O(n) time and space and it can be done in place.  Let x(t) be the input for t=1..n, and let y(t) be the output.  Define x(t)=0 and y(t)=0 for t<1 and t>n.  Define the kernel f(t) to be 1 for 0..d-1 and 0 elsewhere.  The definition for convolution gives us the following formula:

> y(t) = sum i x(t-i) * f(i) = sum i=0..d-1 x(t-i)

This looks like it takes time O(n*d), but we can rewrite it as a recurrence:

> y(t) = y(t-1) + x(t) - x(t-d)

This shows that the one-dimensional convolution is O(n), independent of d.  To perform the two-dimensional convolution, you simply perform the one-dimensional convolution for each axis.  This works because the boxcar kernel can be decomposed: in general, most kernels cannot be decomposed.  The Gaussian kernel is another kernel that can be decomposed, which is why Gaussian blur in an image editing program is so fast.

**For the kind of numbers you specify,** this will be extremely fast.  500x500 is an extremely small data set, and your computer can check 202,500 regions in a few milliseconds at most.  You will have to ask yourself whether it is worth the extra hours, days, or weeks of time it will take you to optimize further.

This is the same as justhalf's solution, except due to the decomposed convolution, the region size does not affect the algorithm's speed.

### Algorithm 2

Assume there is at least one point.  Without loss of generality, consider the 2D space to be the entire plane.  Let *d* be the width and height of the region.  Let N be the number of points.

**Lemma:** There exists a region of maximum density which has a point on its left edge.

**Proof:** Let R be a region of maximum density.  Let R' be the same region, translated right by the distance between the left edge of R and the leftmost point in R.  All points in R must also lie in R', therefore R' is also a region of maximum density.

#### The algorithm

1. Insert all points into a K-D tree.  This can be done in O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) time.
2. For each point, consider the region of width *d* and height 2*d* where the point is centered on the left edge of the region.  Call this region R.
3. Query the K-D tree for the points in region R.  Call this set S.  This can be done in O(N<sup>1/2</sup>+|S|) time.
4. Find the d x d subregion of R containing the largest number of points in S.  This can be done in O(|S| log |S|) time by sorting S by y-coordinate and then performing a linear scan.

The resulting algorithm has a time of O(N<sup>3/2</sup> + N |S| log |S|).

### Comparison

Algorithm #1 is superior to algorithm #2 when the density is high.  Algorithm #2 is only superior when the density of particles is very low, and the density at which algorithm #2 is superior decreases as the total board size increases.

Note that the continuous case can be considered to have zero density, at which point only algorithm #2 works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overlapping regions... we are only searching for one region, there are 202,500 possible checks.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Performance and optimization are important, but it is premature.  After all, the first rule of optimization is, "don't".

Comment: @MillieSmith: The method I have proposed does not depend on the size of the region.  The constant factors inside the O() are *very small* constant factors.  I have at least proposed a *complete* and *correct* solution, if you claim that a more efficient solution exists than by all means enlighten me.  Otherwise you are just guessing that I am wrong.

Comment: @MillieSmith: I am not playing devil's advocate.  I was commenting on incomplete solutions.  It doesn't matter how fast your code is if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MillieSmith: you seemed to be playing "ad hominem", which seemed to be caused by DietrichEpp criticizing your idea in the question comments.

Comment: Btw Dietrich, your main idea seems to be hanging around convolution. I guess you need to describe that in more details. (Also I'm interested what is special with 50x50 in 500x500 that you can accomplish the task in `O(n)` time)

Comment: It seems that "MillieSmith"'s comments have been deleted, but maybe I have the same question as she did: how do you claim O(n) time for Algorithm 1, when AFAICT you need time proportional to O(nd^2) for a d-by-d square region?  (d being 50 in the OP's question.)  I can see how an O(nd) algorithm might be possible if you "decompose" the convolution as you say, but there is still a dependence on d, is there not?  (Here I'm following your lead by taking n = # of grid cells, though I'd usually prefer to write n = width of grid cells and write O(n^2*d^2).)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: A decomposed box convolution takes amortized constant time per cell.  There is no dependence on d, and there is only a linear dependence on the number of dimensions.  In the one-dimensional case, given inputs x(1)..x(n), the formula for the output y(t) can be given by y(t) = sum i=0..d-1 x(i+t), which is indeed O(n*d).  However, that is equivalent to the recurrence relation y(t) = y(t-1) + x(t+d-1) - x(t-1), which is O(n).  This shortcut is why convolution by the boxcar function is so efficient for discrete inputs.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks.  I've +1ed your comment, but since this is critical to the performance of the algorithm and seems to have escaped other answerers, could you mention it in the main post?  I'll then +1 it.

Comment: Also I think it's worth mentioning that these 2 convolutions can be done in-place -- i.e. no second memory buffer is needed to hold their outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what brute force method you use, but the most brute force way would be `O(n^2 d^2)`, by iterating over every region in `O(n^2)` time, then count the number of particles in that region in `O(d^2)` time where `d` is the size of your region.

This problem is exactly the same as this problem: [Rat Attack](http://poj.org/problem?id=1916), since the region area is fixed, and so the density is the same as the count,
for which the solution is `O(n^2 + k*d^2)`, where

1. `n` is the size of the whole area (length of the side)
2. `k` is the number of particles
3. `d` is the size of each region (length of the side)

by this algorithm:

1. For each particle, update the count of the `O(d^2)` regions affected by this particle
2. Iterate over all `O(n^2)` possible regions, find the maximum

as shown in [this code](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/uva-10360-rat-attack/), I copy the relevant part here for your reference:

```cpp
using namespace std;

int mat [1024 + 3] [1024 + 3]; // Here n is assumed to be 1024

int main ()
{
    int testCases; scanf ("%d", &testCases);

    while ( testCases-- ) {

        Set(mat, 0);

        int d; scanf ("%d", &d); // d is the size of the region
        int k; scanf ("%d", &k); // k is the number of particles

        int x, y, cost;

        for ( int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
            scanf ("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &cost); // Read each particle position

            // Update the count of the d^2 region affected by this particle
            for ( int j = max (0, x - d); j <= min (x + d, 1024); j++ ) {
                for ( int k = max (0, y - d); k <= min (y + d, 1024); k++ ) mat [j] [k] += cost;
            }
        }

        int resX, resY, maxi = -1;

        // Find the maximum count over all regions
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1025; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 1025; j++ ) {
                if ( maxi < mat [i] [j] ) {
                    maxi = mat [i] [j];
                    resX = i;
                    resY = j;
                }
            }
        }

        printf ("%d %d %d\n", resX, resY, maxi);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've put my comments in the code to explain it to you.

Comment: A runtime of O(n^2 + k) is possible with slight modifications, because updating each d*d size region can be done all at once with a decomposed box convolution in O(n^2) time.

Comment: Wow, you seem to know much more than I do. Can you describe what decomposed box convolution is? And also can you provide some link to K-D tree in your answer?

Comment: Convolution is the process where you take each cell, and add its contents to neighboring cells.  (You can also scale the value by a constant when you add it to neighboring cells.)  You do this with all cells at the same time.  The kernel is the set of neighboring cells that you affect, and the coefficient for each cell.  The box function is a kernel which is just a rectangle with a constant value everywhere inside.  The box function can be decomposed into two one-dimensional convolutions (the Gaussian kernel also has this property) which makes it very fast to compute the convolution.

Comment: Gaussian blur is another example of a convolution, the convolution with the Gaussian kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the region into 1000x1000 and count the number of particles in every (overlapping) 2x2. You can partition them simply by normalizing 0..1, scaling 0..999, and casting to integer. Counts can easily be stored as a 2D array of integers (ushort, uint, or ulong... mmmm tea). This is equivalent to simple 2D spatial partitioning used in broad-phase collision detection.