# How can I pick an intelligent location from a list of points/coordinates on 2D tile map?

Tags: algorithm, search, location, 2d, point

So I have an arrayList of the locations of each pixel (represent resources in my game). arrayList.get(0); would get me the top right point, and then continuing by increment the x coordinate. When it reaches the end, it increments the y coordinate and repeats until it gets to the last point (left-most, bottom)/end of the list.

I want to build a factory site, but first I need to pick an intelligent location to build my factory/resource site. See picture (red is an ideal location). 
If I simply take an average of all points, it would give me somewhere around orange arrow (I'm guessing).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the highest point density.  [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533370/best-way-to-efficiently-find-high-density-regions) discusses a couple of algorithms, the first doing box convolution.

Of course if each pixel just has value 1 this may be more than you need.