# Concave Hull of subset 2D Points of fixed area that maximizes contained points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, point, concave-hull

I have a set of 2D points, and I'd like to find a subset of those points from which the concave hull (or alpha-shape of a specific alpha) is below a specific threshold, but maximizes the number of points contained in the subset.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about the number of points, and also the ratio between the threshold area and the area of the total convex hull?

Comment: If the threshold is only slightly lower than the total convex hull area, then I suggest you could start from the whole set of points, then eliminate points following a [simulated annealing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: If the threshold is very small compared to the total convex hull area, then instead you should probably try to find [high-density regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533370/best-way-to-efficiently-find-high-density-regions) and start expanding the set of points from these regions until you can't expand anymore. (Maybe still in a simulated annealing fashion, but increasing the number of points from below the threshold rather than decreasing the number of points from above the threshold)

Comment: Consider a regular polygon with an area equal to the threshold and add small random perturbations to the vertices. Considering the convex hull (α=0), the problem seems to tend to the subset-sum, which is known to be in NP. I see no reason that nonzero α would make it easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll look into that!
The ratio should indeed be quite small in most cases? But it depends on each case to be honest. But in the majority of cases, it should be much lower (maybe 1/50th ?)